# PL/PgSQL Dynamic Subqueries

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, plpgsql

I am creating a trigger that runs a check raises an exception if it passes. To do this I need to use a dynamic call because I only have the table name as a string. I am using PostgreSQL but I can't figure out how there execute command works. When I do this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bleep() RETURNS table(id INT) AS $bleep$
  BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT (id) from Applicant';
  END;
$bleep$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * from bleep();
```

It works perfectly and I get back a table of id's from Applicant. But when I do this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bleep() RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $bleep$
  BEGIN
    IF (EXISTS (EXECUTE 'SELECT (id) from Applicant')) THEN
      RETURN TRUE;
    ELSE
      RETURN FALSE;
    END IF;
  END;
$bleep$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

It tells me:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "EXECUTE" Position: 87

This is just a toy example I made to figure out how this works and I have read lots of docs and guides. If I can figure out this toy example I can make the full trigger work since I tried it with hardcoding a table name. How can I make this work?

Comment: Unrelated, but: do not get into the habit to put column names between parentheses. While `(id)` and `id` are the same thing, `(a,b)` and `a,b` are very different.

Comment: What are you trying to test *exactly*. Whether a column named `id` exists in the given table? Or whether there are any rows in the table? The best solution depends on this crucial information. (And you undeclared version of Postgres.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bleep() RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $bleep$
  DECLARE
        res bool;
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'SELECT exists (select 1 from Applicant)' INTO res;
    return res;
  END;
$bleep$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bleep() RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $bleep$
  BEGIN
    return query EXECUTE 'SELECT exists (select 1 from Applicant)';
  END;
$bleep$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: When I tried this it told me: `ERROR: cannot use RETURN QUERY in a non-SETOF function Position: 75`

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bleep() RETURNS 
BOOLEAN AS $bleep$
  BEGIN
    IF (EXISTS (SELECT id from Applicant)) THEN
      RETURN TRUE;
    ELSE
      RETURN FALSE;
    END IF;
  END;
$bleep$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: While this solves the problem of the specific example in mind, I said that I need to use a dynamic query since this is a toy example for something that does require a dynamic query.

Comment: @user5505266 You right, I answered another that using dynamic query.

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood your question.
How about this?

```
CREATE FUNCTION bleep(integer) RETURNS boolean
    AS 'select case when count(*) = 0 then false else true end from Applicant where id = $1;'
LANGUAGE SQL
IMMUTABLE
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;
```

You can test by SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/33954/1